# serverless how to change destination directory of the included package

Tags: typescript, serverless-framework

I have a lambda function built using serverless framework. I need to include some static files which are contained within the folder `templates` `src/templates/somefile.hbs`

The serverless framework allows us to include these files using `package.include`

```
   package: { individually: true, include: ["src/templates/*"] },
```

However the end result inside of build looks like this .

[image]

However i need it to be `templates` without `src`. Is there some way to copy templates only

```
const source = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, `templates/${templateName}.hbs`), "utf8");
```

Comment: I don't find anyway to do this in their documentation. Do you really need `templates` to be at root level ? Can't you reference it as `src/templates`. If so, why templates aren't stored directly under root `/templates` and `/src` both in root level ?

Comment: An [issue](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3366) exists and has been fixed by a [plugin](https://github.com/hypoport/serverless-custom-packaging-plugin) which I wouldn't rely as no support is really provided and no news about serverless 3.17 so far.

Comment: A last solution is to implement a step during your build phase, like compiling everything in a `/dist` folder and copying your templates in it as a step in `package.json`